# Is there a way to support 'const reference' as a function signature parameter in my generic function router design?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to make a function router that calls correct function from `std::map<uint64_t, std::function<void(T)>>` map. The problem is, it can only find certain kinds of functions with certain kind of function signatures. I want it to support all kinds of functions.

### Library itself:

```cpp
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Engine
{
public:

  typedef std::uint64_t hash_t;

  /* Register function to signal router. */
  template<class T>
  void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T)) {
    /* Cast function ptr to std::function. */
    auto func = static_cast<std::function<void (T)>>(f);
    signal_router<T>[hash] = func;
  }

  /* Call registerd function from signal router. */
  template<class T>
  void emit(hash_t hash, T&& param) {
    try {
      signal_router<T>[hash](param);
    } catch (std::bad_function_call&) {
      int status = -4;
      std::cerr << "Signal router: no function implemented for parameter \""
                << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), nullptr, nullptr, &status) << "\" " << '\n';
    }
  }
private:
  template<typename T>
  static std::map<hash_t, std::function<void (T)>> signal_router;
};

/* We must declare static instance outside of its class, altough it's private. */
template<typename T>
typename::std::map<uint64_t, std::function<void (T)>> Engine::signal_router;

#endif /* ENGINE_H */
```

### Usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include "engine.hpp"

void f1(int i) {
  std::cout << "Hello " << i << '\n';
}

void f2(long i) {
  std::cout << "Hello " << i << '\n';
}

void f3(std::string& i) {
  std::cout << "Hello " << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  Engine eng;

  eng.attach(0, f1);
  eng.emit(0, 1);

  eng.attach(1, f2);
  eng.emit(1, 10l);

  eng.attach(2, f3);
  std::string s = " world";
  eng.emit(2, s);

  return 0;
}
```

### Outputs:

```
Hello 1
Hello 10
Hello world
```

Which is correct.

But if I change `void f3(std::string& i)` signature to `void f3(const std::string& i)` it fails. As I understand, the template function is created with const parameter but it stripped out at some point and doesn't find correct the function from function map.

If I change the function `f3` parameter to `const std::string&` it outputs:

```cpp
Signal router: no function implemented for parameter "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >"
```

So the const is stripped out.

How can I support all kinds of parameters (const ref, ref, values, etc...) through my template design?

Comment: You might use `eng.emit<const string&>(2, s);`.

Comment: My original intention was to hide as much as detail as possible. IMO this syntax is confusing. It would make more sense if the template was used for return type, not as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we originally attach the function, if the function parameter is `const`, then it's safe to also bind a mutable version:

```
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T)) {
  /* Bind to signal rounter */
  signal_router<T>[hash] = std::function<void(T)>(f); 

  /* Bind mutable version to signal router */
  using PlainT = std::remove_reference_t<T>; 
  if(std::is_reference<T>::value && std::is_const<PlainT>::value) {
      // Bind mutable version
      using MutableT = std::remove_const_t<PlainT>&;
      signal_router<MutableT>[hash] = std::function<void(MutableT)>(f); 
  }
}
```

Then, we can write `f3` as a const function:

```
void f3(std::string const& i) {
  std::cout << "Hello " << i << '\n';
}
```

And now, `main` works whether or not `std::string` is const.

We can re-write this using pattern matching too:

```
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T)) {
  // if it's pass by value, add multiple binds for references
  signal_router<T>[hash] = std::function<void(T)>(f); 
  signal_router<T&>[hash] = std::function<void(T&)>(f); 
  signal_router<T const&>[hash] = std::function<void(T const&)>(f); 
  signal_router<T&&>[hash] = std::function<void(T&&)>(f); 
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T&)) {
  signal_router<T&>[hash] = std::function<void(T&)>(f); 
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(const T&)) {
  signal_router<T const&>[hash] = std::function<void(T const&)>(f); 
  signal_router<T&>[hash] = std::function<void(T&)>(f); 
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T&&)) {
  signal_router<T&&>[hash] = std::function<void(T&&)>(f); 
}
```

Comment: It is quite difficult to have `emit` call both `signal_router<T>` and `signal_router<T&&>`...  one of them is probably unused by whatever implementation of `emit` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you don't support volatile.

Here are the 5 types that can be in the signature of your function pointers:

```
int
int const&
int &
int const&&
int &&
```

In your design, you cannot pass a pure `int` in.  So we only have to worry about it as a function pointer argument.

`int` can be called by any of the above.

`int const&` can be called by any of the above.

`int const&&` can be called by `int&&`.

`int&` and `int&&` cannot be called by anything else.

Now, if our type is movable but not-copyable, the rules change.

`T` can only be called by `T&&`.

`T const&` can still be called by anyone.

If our type is non-movable, then `T` cannot be called via a proxy wrapper without an `emplace` system.

At the point of call, we need to invert this.  If called with `T&` `T const&` and `T&`.  If `T` can be copied, also check `T`.

If called with `T const&` we only check `T const&` and `T` iff `T` can be copied.

If called with `T&&` we need to check `T&&` and `T const&&` and `T const&` and `T` iff `T` can be moved.

If called with `T const&&` we only check `T const&&` and `T` if `T` can be copied.

So this gives us a plan of attack.

```
template<class T>
void populate(has_t hash, std::function<void(T)> f) {
  signal_router<T>[hash] = std::move(f);
}

template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T&)) {
  populate<T&>(hash, f);
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(const T&)) {
  populate<T const&>(hash, f); 
  populate<T&>(hash, f); 
  populate<T&&>(hash, f); 
  populate<T const&&>(hash, f);
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T&&)) {
  populate<T&&>(hash, f);
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T const&&)) {
  populate<T&&>(hash, f);
  populate<T const&&>(hash, f);
}
template<class T>
void attach(hash_t hash, void(*f)(T)) {
  if constexpr( std::is_copy_constructible<T>{} ) {
    populate<T const&>(hash, f);
    populate<T&>(hash, f);
    populate<T const&&>(hash, f);
  }
  if constexpr( std::is_move_constructible<T>{} ) {
    populate<T&&>(hash, f);
  }
}
```

and emit is:

```
template<class T>
void emit(hash_t hash, T&& param) {
  try {
    signal_router<T&&>[hash](param);
  }
```

`volatile` support would require another pass.

This used some C++17; there are ways around the `if constexpr`.   I'd use tag dispatching.

Comment: Yup, I don't need `volatile`.